# Converting data into ENVI format

Tags: python, image-processing, header-files, image-preprocessing, envi

I have data acquisition from Hyperspectral image scanner and now my task is to convert the image(.png and .jpg format) in to different form, let's say ENVi header file or Open cv or MATLAB.
IS Envi format is similar to file folder which contains data and header files?If not, Is it possible to create a file which contains data and header files?
I want to do it in Python. Looking for some reference material to understand it in better way!
Thank You.

Comment: It is unclear, to me at least, what format your data is currently in.

Comment: AFAIK `PNG` and `JPEG` images are not normally considered *"hyperspectral"* ?

Comment: Hello again Mark, Suppose I am taking the image from Spectrometer(raw data in .csv which I got in my first data acquisition step) and now I want to convert it into ENVI header file without using software and using Python programming. Is it possible to do so? I am pretty new to this conversions! Do you have any suggested procedures or papers to know more about it ?

Comment: Now it is even more unclear - your hyperspectral data which you originally said was `JPEG`, or maybe `PNG`, is actually CSV! And your output format seems unclear too - is it ENVI or OpenCV or Matlab? Anyway... it's been a while since I did anything with ENVI, but it looks like `GDAL` can maybe write ENVI data/hdr files... https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/envi.html?highlight=envi